# String Aggregation without using ListAgg -- SIMPLE ANSWER (Oracle)

Tags: sql, string, oracle, aggregation

Is there a simple way to do a string aggregation without using ListAgg?  I am new to Oracle and I was trying to use the ListAgg function and it is not working.  I think I have a version installed that is not compatible with ListAgg.  I am essentially trying to the following:

Actual List:

```
Encounter ID  CPT Code  
------------  ---------
123           21556
124           21554
123           92145
123           92542
```

Output:

```
Encounter ID  CPT Code  
------------  ---------
123           21556,92145,92542
124           21554
```

Comment: well, what version are you using?, what's the error message that you get?

Comment: Take a look at `WM_CONCAT` function [here](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php#wm_concat)

Answer (score 1):

This is [Tom Kyte's version of Stragg](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:2196162600402) which he no longer uses as listagg is more efficient. This will aggregate strings up to 4000 characters long.  You must have the grant to create types and functions in your_schema.  The separator cannot be changed dynamically but I leave that as an exercise.

Usage:  select  dept_no, stragg(emp_name) from emp group by dept_no;

```
create or replace type Your_schema.stragg_type as object
(
  string varchar2(4000),

  static function ODCIAggregateInitialize
    ( sctx in out stragg_type )
    return number ,

  member function ODCIAggregateIterate
    ( self  in out stragg_type ,
      value in     varchar2
    ) return number ,

  member function ODCIAggregateTerminate
    ( self        in  stragg_type,
      returnvalue out varchar2,
      flags in number
    ) return number ,

  member function ODCIAggregateMerge
    ( self in out stragg_type,
      ctx2 in     stragg_type
    ) return number
);
/

create or replace type body Your_schema.stragg_type
is

  static function ODCIAggregateInitialize
  ( sctx in out stragg_type )
  return number
  is
  begin

    sctx := stragg_type( null ) ;

    return ODCIConst.Success ;

  end;

  member function ODCIAggregateIterate
  ( self  in out stragg_type ,
    value in     varchar2
  ) return number
  is
  begin

    self.string := self.string || ',' || value ;

    return ODCIConst.Success;

  end;

  member function ODCIAggregateTerminate
  ( self        in  stragg_type ,
    returnvalue out varchar2 ,
    flags       in  number
  ) return number
  is
  begin

    returnValue := ltrim( self.string, ',' );

    return ODCIConst.Success;

  end;

  member function ODCIAggregateMerge
  ( self in out stragg_type ,
    ctx2 in     stragg_type
  ) return number
  is
  begin

    self.string := self.string || ctx2.string;

    return ODCIConst.Success;

  end;

end;
/

create or replace function Your_schema.stragg
  ( input varchar2 )
  return varchar2
  deterministic
  parallel_enable
  aggregate using stragg_type
;
/
```